# Merging pandas dataframes: empty columns created in left

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have several datasets, which I am trying to merge into one. Below, I created fictive simpler smaller datasets to test the method and it worked perfectly fine.

```
examplelog = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80], 
                       'TVD':[10,19.9,28.8,37.7,46.6,55.5,64.4,73.3],
                       'T1':[11,11.3,11.5,12.,12.3,12.6,13.,13.8],
                       'T2':[11.3,11.5,11.8,12.2,12.4,12.7,13.1,14.1]})

log1 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[30,40,50,60],'T3':[12.1,12.6,13.7,14.]})


log2 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[20,30,40,50,60],'T4':[12.0,12.2,12.4,13.2,14.1]})

logs=[log1,log2]

result=examplelog.copy()

for i in logs:
    result=result.merge(i,how='left', on='Depth')
print result
```

The result is, as expected:

```
Depth    T1    T2   TVD    T3    T4
0     10  11.0  11.3  10.0   NaN   NaN
1     20  11.3  11.5  19.9   NaN  12.0
2     30  11.5  11.8  28.8  12.1  12.2
3     40  12.0  12.2  37.7  12.3  12.4
4     50  12.3  12.4  46.6  13.5  13.2
5     60  12.6  12.7  55.5  14.2  14.1
6     70  13.0  13.1  64.4   NaN   NaN
7     80  13.8  14.1  73.3   NaN   NaN
```

Happy with the result, I applied this method to my actual data, but for T3 and T4 in the resulting dataframes, I received just empty columns (all values were NaN). I suspect that the problem is with floating numbers, because my datasets were created on different machines by different software and although the "Depth" has the precision of two decimal numbers in all of the files, I am afraid that it may not be 20.05 in both of them, but one might be 20.049999999999999 while in the other it might be 20.05000000000001. Then, the merge function will not work, as shown in the following example:

```
examplelog = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80], 
                           'TVD':[10,19.9,28.8,37.7,46.6,55.5,64.4,73.3],
                           'T1':[11,11.3,11.5,12.,12.3,12.6,13.,13.8],
                           'T2':[11.3,11.5,11.8,12.2,12.4,12.7,13.1,14.1]})

log1 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[30.05,40.05,50.05,60.05],'T3':[12.1,12.6,13.7,14.]})


log2 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[20.01,30.01,40.01,50.01,60.01],'T4':[12.0,12.2,12.4,13.2,14.1]})

logs=[log1,log2]

result=examplelog.copy()

for i in logs:
    result=result.merge(i,how='left', on='Depth')
print result

   Depth    T1    T2   TVD  T3  T4
0     10  11.0  11.3  10.0 NaN NaN
1     20  11.3  11.5  19.9 NaN NaN
2     30  11.5  11.8  28.8 NaN NaN
3     40  12.0  12.2  37.7 NaN NaN
4     50  12.3  12.4  46.6 NaN NaN
5     60  12.6  12.7  55.5 NaN NaN
6     70  13.0  13.1  64.4 NaN NaN
7     80  13.8  14.1  73.3 NaN NaN
```

Do you know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Round the `Depth` values to the appropriate precision:

```
for df in [examplelog, log1, log2]:
    df['Depth'] = df['Depth'].round(1)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

examplelog = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80], 
                           'TVD':[10,19.9,28.8,37.7,46.6,55.5,64.4,73.3],
                           'T1':[11,11.3,11.5,12.,12.3,12.6,13.,13.8],
                           'T2':[11.3,11.5,11.8,12.2,12.4,12.7,13.1,14.1]})

log1 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[30.05,40.05,50.05,60.05],'T3':[12.1,12.6,13.7,14.]})
log2 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[20.01,30.01,40.01,50.01,60.01],
                     'T4':[12.0,12.2,12.4,13.2,14.1]})

for df in [examplelog, log1, log2]:
    df['Depth'] = df['Depth'].round(1)

logs=[log1,log2]
result=examplelog.copy()
for i in logs:
    result=result.merge(i,how='left', on='Depth')
print(result)
```

yields

```
   Depth    T1    T2   TVD    T3    T4
0     10  11.0  11.3  10.0   NaN   NaN
1     20  11.3  11.5  19.9   NaN  12.0
2     30  11.5  11.8  28.8  12.1  12.2
3     40  12.0  12.2  37.7  12.6  12.4
4     50  12.3  12.4  46.6  13.7  13.2
5     60  12.6  12.7  55.5  14.0  14.1
6     70  13.0  13.1  64.4   NaN   NaN
7     80  13.8  14.1  73.3   NaN   NaN
```

---

Per the comments, rounding does not appear to work for the OP on the actual
data. To debug the problem, find some rows which should merge:

```
subframes = []
for frame in [examplelog, log2]:
    mask = (frame['Depth'] < 20.051) & (frame['Depth'] >= 20.0)
    subframes.append(frame.loc[mask])
```

Then post

```
for frame in subframes:
    print(frame.to_dict('list')) 
    print(frame.info())          # shows the dtypes of the columns
```

This might give us the info we need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see, this works really well on the example, but still not on my data :(. Any ideas what else might be wrong with the data? Visually I can't see any problem or anything different...Thanks.

Comment: I've added a suggestion on how to debug the problem, above.

Comment: Thanks! so this is what I get: 
`Depth          1 non-null float64` (and for TVD)
and for the rest of the data `0 non-null float64`
(this is confusing, does it mean that I lose ALL the data during the merging process?)

Comment: `0 non-null` means no data was selected *before* the merge. That means there were no `Depth` values between `20.049` and `20.051`. You might need to change the numbers to grab some rows. The goal is to create a small runnable example that reproduces the problem you are seeing. `frame.to_dict('list')` will (hopefully) give us the data we would need to make such an example.